# Mex cannot find a file, but "which" can

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to compile a C++ function (found [here](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Faddeeva_Package)).  I downloaded the requisite packages, installed Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1, linked it to MATLAB using `mex -setup`, and then unzipped the function packages into my MATLAB path.

When I run the command:

```
mex -output Faddeeva_w -O Faddeeva_w_mex.cc Faddeeva.cc
```

I get the error message:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: 'Faddeeva_w_mex.cc' not found.
```

But if I type `which Faddeeva_w_mex.cc` I get:

```
C:\Users\craigim\Documents\Code\Matlab\Faddeeva-MATLAB\Faddeeva_w_mex.cc
```

So MATLAB and the `which` command have no problems finding the file, but `mex` is lost.  This is my very first attempt at compiling something with `mex`, so I'm really not sure where to start here.  Does `mex` have a different path variable that I have to set?

I'm using MATLAB 2013a on a Windows 7 64bit machine with the version of SDK 7.1 that was linked from the MATLAB [List of supported compilers](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/index.html).

Comment: `which` is a witch... and sometimes a b$%#ch...

Comment: Try adding the `-v` flag to your call to `mex` and see whether the verbose information gives you anything more to go on.

Comment: it's quite straightforward in this case: just download the zip file, unzip it, `cd` into that directory and run `Faddeeva_build`. I just tried it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `cd` into the directory containing the files (assuming they both in the same place), or specify full/relative path to the C++ files when invoking `mex` function

Comment: I had all the other parts, but `cd`ing into the directory is what made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `addpath('C:\Users\craigim\Documents\Code\Matlab\Faddeeva-MATLAB\');` in your m-file. The path that MATLAB uses seems to be internal and independent of whatever your OS is using.

[Documentation on addpath here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html).

[And a similar discussion here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/288272).

You may also have to set your PATH environment variable to the string returned by the command `fullfile(matlabroot,'bin',computer('arch'))` in MATLAB. Here are some instructions on setting environment variables for [Windows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-with-the-mex-command.html#bsrhbfs-1) and [Mac or Linux](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-with-the-mex-command.html#bsrhcqr-1)

There is also a [pretty good overview of building mex-files here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-mex-files.html) although I get the impression that the basics are not going to answer your question.

Comment: I have a variation of that command in my custom `startup.m` file.  That's why `which` finds the file. I also separately verified that the file is in the MATLAB path before running `mex`, so that isn't the problem.

Comment: You may also have to set your PATH environment variable as indicated in the edit above.